# pdo and like query

Tags: php, pdo, sql-like

**I have a query and it looks like:**

```
if (strlen($search->q)) {

    $where[]        = ' AND (`name` LIKE :q)';
    $arr['q']       = "%" . $search->q . "%";
}

$sql = 'SELECT 
                *,
        FROM 
            `shop_products`
        WHERE 
            1=1
            '.implode('', $where);
```

**Not I'm trying to get products from DB:**

```
$result->products   = $db->query($sql, $arr, $search->limitstart, $search->limit)->fetchAll();
```

**My query function:**

```
public function query($sql, $params=array(), $offset = null, $limit = null){

            if (!is_null($offset) && !is_null($limit)) {
                $sql .= ' LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
                $params['limit']        =  (int)$limit;
                $params['offset']       =   (int)$offset;
            }

            $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql); 

            if (!empty($params)) {      
                foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                    if(is_int($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    } elseif(is_null($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    } elseif(is_string($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                    } else {
                        $param = false;
                    }

                    if($param) $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value, $param);
                }
            }

            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
 }
```

My problem that `LIKE` instruction does not work. How can I solve this problem and fix my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "*LIKE instruction does not work*"? What is the output? What do you expect?

Comment: SQL return empty result from DB.

Comment: FYI, you can do `$stmt->execute($params)` instead of that loop.

Comment: Do you have PDO exceptions enabled?

Comment: You could also use $stmt->errorInfo();